# invalid cast exception from string """"

Tags: .net, vb.net

hi i have had this same really irritating problem a few times in vb now and i don't understand why. on this code

```
 Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        While True
            Console.Title = "discount orders"
            Console.Clear()
            Console.WriteLine("please enter the value of the order {0}£", vbNewLine)
            Dim order As Double = CDbl(Console.ReadLine())
            Select Case order
                Case 0 To 1000
                    order = order
                Case 1000 To 2500
                    order = order * 0.95
                Case 2500 To 5000
                    order = order * 0.9
                Case 5000 To 10000
                    order = order * 0.85
                Case > 10000
                    order = order * 0.8

            End Select
            Console.WriteLine("the discounted price is £{0}", order)
            Console.Read()
        End While
    End Sub

End Module
```

it works the first time however when loop is run for a second time it breaks on line 8 because it cant convert from string to double

Comment: May you remove Console.Read() line & Console.Clear() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is it happening?

```
Console.Read()
...
Console.Clear()
```

A single character is read, then the console is cleared. So when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, a carriage return and line feed are input to the console, and just the carriage return (char 13) is read, then the console is cleared. The line feed (char 10) is still there and is used for the next input. Instead of `Console.Read()`, use `Console.ReadLine()` to consume both characters.

Also, add some validation so your application doesn't crash when a non-numeric value is entered.

```
Sub Main()
    Console.Title = "discount orders"
    While True
        Console.Clear()
        ' Console.Write so the £ is before the input
        Console.Write("please enter the value of the order {0}£", Environment.NewLine)
        ' this is the user's input
        Dim input = Console.ReadLine()
        Dim order As Double
        ' try to parse a number, if not this is false
        If Double.TryParse(input, order) Then
            Select Case order
                Case 0 To 1000
                    order = order
                Case 1000 To 2500
                    order = order * 0.95
                Case 2500 To 5000
                    order = order * 0.9
                Case 5000 To 10000
                    order = order * 0.85
                Case > 10000
                    order = order * 0.8
            End Select
            Console.WriteLine("the discounted price is £{0}", order)
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' not a valid input. try again", input)
        End If
        ' ReadLine to consume both the carriage return and line feed
        Console.ReadLine()
    End While
End Sub
```

Examples

Valid entry:

> please enter the value of the order
>   
> £2345
>   
> the discounted price is £2227.75

Invalid entry:

> please enter the value of the order
>   
> £322k
>   
> '322k' not a valid input. try again

Comment: I agree that this works, but the Try/Catch isn't necessary. `TryParse` will return `False` if the input is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you validate the input before proceed to next step.

```
Sub Main()
    While True
        Console.Title = "discount orders"
        Console.Clear()
        Console.WriteLine("please enter the value of the order {0}£", vbNewLine)
        Try
            Dim input As UInteger
            If UInteger.TryParse(Console.ReadLine, input) Then
                Dim order As Double = Convert.ToDouble(input)
                Select Case order
                    Case 0 To 1000
                        order = order
                    Case 1000 To 2500
                        order = order * 0.95
                    Case 2500 To 5000
                        order = order * 0.9
                    Case 5000 To 10000
                        order = order * 0.85
                    Case Is > 10000
                        order = order * 0.8
                End Select
                Console.WriteLine("the discounted price is £{0}", order)
                Console.Read()
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("Please insert only numbers")
                Console.Read()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Error!- {0}", ex.Message)
            Console.Read()
        End Try
    End While
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that the `Console.Read()` is getting the next character from the console and if you hit <kbd>enter</kbd> then that's two characters - a `"\r\n"` - so the `Read` gets one and then the subsequent `ReadLine` immediately returns because it thinks that the `"\n"` is the end of your input. Then you get the error.

Instead you should make the `.Read()` a `.ReadLine()` and ask the user to hit enter to continue.